# Is there a CGAL function for calculating the area of a linear polygon with holes (Polygon_with_holes_2)?

Tags: c++, cgal

I want to find out the area of a Polygon_with_holes_2. I understand that there is a Polygon_2 method `area`. However, that can only calculate the area of a Polygon_2 (without holes).

I also realise it is extremely simple to write my own function to simply subtract the absolute area of all the holes from the absolute area of the outer boundary. However, I'd much prefer a CGAL function that is already included in the library.

Comment: In fact there is no need to subtract areas of two polygons.  The area of a polygon is the sum of signed areas of triangles with the origin and the vertices on each edge, and that carries over to the polygons with holes.  We will have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm kind of confused what you mean by the sum of signed areas of triangles with the origin and the vertices on each edge. Further, how may find the sum of the signed area of said triangles?